# How do I get MySQL to work with Sign In Manger in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: c#, mysql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am currently working on a website that will use asp.net MVC 5, however because of SQL Server limitations, I wish for it to use MySQL instead. However, when trying to do so I get an error "The entity type ApplicationUser is not part of the model for the current context"

This error happens when ever I try to ge the username and password I have stored in the database. All relevant code is the same as what was in the default template except that the ApplicationDbContext() function in the IdentityModel class has its connection string to go to the MySQL server.

I have already installed the connector and plugin for MySQL to work in visual studio 2015, and I can do Queries via the MySQL api, so there is no problem with the connection between the program and MySQL.

Any thought what is going on, I am very new to ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: have you checked google or msdn search on how to query database using MVC5 and MySql perhaps there is a connection string issue check out this site for how to connect to different databases using web.config file 
[ConnectionString](http://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/)

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the steps in the below link, if you have any confusion, please comment.

https://codeimp.wordpress.com/2014/11/28/migration-of-asp-membership-to-mvc5-identity-using-mysql/